# too many thank you emails

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

this is the process so far:

Recruiter "A" emailed me to take an online coding test. I thanked "A".

"A" set me up with another recruiter. I thanked "A" for the opportunity.

"A" set me up with a developer for another interview. Thanked "A".

I just finished the interview, and am debating whether to thank "A" again. It seems even worse because the last email I was talking to her in was something like:

"Her: You will now be set up with developer for interview.

Me: Thank you, am confirming I will be ready for interview."

So the next thank you I send will be right below that last thank you. Is this too much?

Comment: Thank you is not needed. Most recruiters/interviewers are sick of this emails which add no value.

Comment: OP, are you talking about external or internal recruiters?

Answer (score 2):

This is an opinion-based question. I usually don't write an email to just say thank you, because I assume the recruiter is very busy. I don't clog up his/her inbox unless I have a question or am due for an update on my job application.

In this case, I would write:

> Hi A,
>
> I enjoyed interviewing with DEVELOPER on DATE for ROLE. Could you tell me when I will hear back about next steps?
>
> Thank you,
>
> user3613290

Comment: If the question is opinion-based (I don't think it is) then you should be voting or flagging to close, not answering it.

Comment: This is very different from my experience.  For me, recruiters want an immediate post-interview call and a detailed report of what happened.

Comment: @emory I get that more a 3rd party recruiter/headhunter/sourcer. Internal recruiters are informed before the candidate.

Comment: @Lilienthal I flagged it as opinion-based. This answer depends on your personal strategy. Some candidates love to bombard the recruiter with email, voicemails, etc about anything so that you're always "on the top of stack." I find this tactic annoying and a waste of time for both parties. Even StackExchange discourages just "thank you" comments.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this too much?

If you didn't have any other contact with A since your last thank you email and she didn't attend the interview then yes, **this would be a bit much. It won't hurt to do so but it's entirely unnecessary.** A thank you letter is appropriate after having spoken to someone in an interview, but that's presumably not the case here.

Since you don't need to thank her, **the only time you should send a follow-up is if you truly have something to say.** If you really clicked with the interviewer, discovered some new information or have further questions for  A, then you should send her an email and you can include a "thank you for setting this up" as a part of it. Other than that, it's presumably her job to set up interviews and you already thanked her for it once, that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

I often end requests with "thanks in advance" -- so I have thanked the person, but not used an additional/annoying separate email to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**If you really want to thank the recruiter, consider calling them to give them a little report on how the interview went.**

My personal experience with recruiters is that they are interested in that information, since it helps them confirm whether or not they accurately matched what the company was looking for with a candidate profile (yours in this case) as well as get an idea of what questions the interviewers were asking which in turn helps the recruiter get a more accurate idea of exactly what the company is looking for. It's much easier to convey this information through a phone conversation though, since it allows them to ask for the details they are interested in directly instead of having to send another mail and wait for the response etc. in which case they probably won't even bother.

When calling them, I would do so like this:

> Hello X, I'm calling to see if you're interested in some details on how the interview went.

This gives them the opportunity to decline, start asking about the details they are interested in, or let you give them a general description and leave it at that.